# Is it possible to auto wire a bean inside a bean annotated with @FeignClient

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, feign

I define a feign client as below, I want to auto wire a service bean called variableSerivce, but when the program starts, the variableService is not initialized, are there any workarounds to auto wire it? thanks!

```
@FeignClient(name = "myFeign", url = '${some-url}')
interface MyApiClient {
  final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SacombankApiClient.class)

  @Autowired
VariableService variableService
...
}
```

Comment: No. You cannot autowired into an interface. Also would be quite weird to inject something here as it is a `@FeignClient`.

Comment: A workaround would be to get the bean from spring application context runtime. Something like:
ApplicationContextHolder.getApplicationContext().getBean("beanName");

Comment: You cannot do that in an interface and it definitly doesn't make sense in an `@FeignClient`.